# error is coming Cannot read properties of null (reading 'store')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to pass data from redux store to other components but  error is coming tried many things.

The code of app.js is as follows which is wrapped in provider

```
import React from 'react';
import Babe from './Babe';
import type { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';
import Test from './navigate/Test';
import Hot from './navigate/Hot';
import Coffee from './navigate/Coffee';
import Tea from './navigate/Tea';
import FullCourse from './navigate/FullCourse';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import FullCourse2 from './navigate/FullCourse2';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/app/store';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { showData } from './src/features/showslice'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

Above sections have all the necessary imports, the below part is where the problem is in the use of `useSelector` hook.

```
const App = () => {
  const data = useSelector((c) => {
    return console.log(c)
  })

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="In-Flight Services" component={Babe} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Cold Water" component={Test} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Hot Water" component={Hot} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Tea" component={Tea} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Coffee" component={Coffee} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Meal" component={FullCourse} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Meal2" component={FullCourse2} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The slice code is as follows, I am trying to access the value of 5 that is `state.value` into app.js.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

// const initialState = { value: 0 }

export const showslice = createSlice({
  name: 'showData',
  initialState: { value: 3 },
  reducers: {
    addData: () => { },
    showData: (state, action) => {
      return state.value = 5
    }
  }
})

export const { addData, showData } = showslice.actions
export default showslice.reducer

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
// the showData in the store which is being assigned represents showslice.reducer
```

The store code is as follows

```js
// import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import showData from '../features/showslice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    show: showData
  },
})

export default store
```

The imports are all correct checked multiple times.

I am expecting the value of `useSelector` to be stored in const `data` in order to display it, but at the line of `useSelector` the error is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App` component is the component rendering the Redux store `Provider` component, so `App` itself ***cannot*** subscribe to the store via the `useSelector` hook. If `App` needs to subscribe to the store then the `Provider` component should be moved higher in the ReactTree than the `App` component trying to access the context it provides.

Example:

`Provider` provides Redux context to its sub-ReactTree.

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

```
const App = () => {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.show.value); // <-- can access store

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="In-Flight Services" component={Babe} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Cold Water" component={Test} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Hot Water" component={Hot} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Tea" component={Tea} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Coffee" component={Coffee} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Meal" component={FullCourse} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Meal2" component={FullCourse2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Additionally, the slice reducers should only mutate the state ***or*** return the next state value, ***but not ever both***.

```js
export const showslice = createSlice({
  name: 'showData',
  initialState: { value: 3 },
  reducers: {
    addData: () => { },
    showData: (state, action) => {
      state.value = 5;
    },
  }
})
```

or

```js
export const showslice = createSlice({
  name: 'showData',
  initialState: { value: 3 },
  reducers: {
    addData: () => { },
    showData: (state, action) => {
      return { value: 5 };
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Tried all the things you pointed out results are same

Comment: @BhavishyaTomer Double check that followed all suggested changes and that you don't have the same issue elsewhere in the app. Try killing and restarting the app. It should work. If the issue persists, see if you can create a ***running*** [codeandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Comment: how about i share snackexpo link?

Comment: @BhavishyaTomer That would work, as long as it's already a running example that we don't need to debug further just to get it running/working.

Comment: @BhavishyaTomer Oh, I see, the `useSelector` line was commented out in the `App` component. Uncommenting that and I see the error.

Comment: @BhavishyaTomer Well, it took a bit of digging, but it seems that the Expo ecosystem has some "optimizations" overtop plain old React-Native. It runs the `App` component by default as the entry point, so the `Provider` component used in index.js was completely ignored. In fact, index.js isn't used at all in Expo. I got it working by renaming `App` to `MyApp` and moving the `Provider` component and store into a "new" `App` component that renders `MyApp`. It all appears to be working now.

Comment: @BhavishyaTomer https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/error-is-coming-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-store?platform=android

Comment: @BhavishyaTomer FWIW my answer here in all likelihood works under all other normal operating circumstances. The issue you were seeing is likely (*what I'd call*) a quirk of using Expo.